# Is allowing uploads of .php files dangerous if only the tmp files content is being used?

Tags: php, security, file-upload

I'm not moving the tmp file to a 'live' (web-accessible) directory at all, simply doing a `file_get_contents` on the tmp file and running a few regexes against it (the code is *never* executed/run).

Could this be dangerous or pose any risks?

Comment: And what do you do with the code afterwards? Is it ever being executed?

Comment: @deceze The code is never executed/run, I simply run a few regexes against the files content.

Comment: All uploaded files are deleted after execution of your php code. So if you do not require them later, there is no risk of data loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you’re not executing it, the file is nothing more than a plain text file. Check the file size and type as you would with any other data file and you should be safe.

If you later decide to make it web accessible (for whatever reason), make sure you set permissions on it (in a Linux environment) or change the file extension (under Windows) so that it cannot be executed.

Answer (score 0):

This will somewhat depend on your environment.

File upload itself it not harmful unless your environment is not Windows. In that case, I'd employ an antivirus program to check the file before any processing is done on it.

Also, file size matters. `file_get_contents` will read the **whole file** into your server's memory at once. So, if the file is too big or your resources too low, you may run into errors.

That's probably all I'd be worried about if I'm not presenting uploaded content to my users.

Comment: I don't understand your point about using an antivirus on a text file regardless of the environment.

Comment: I always reserve some space for unforeseen server faults - like an overflow in the server that would call the file to leak somewhere where it does not belong (memory-wise) - and boom, it's executed :) ... but maybe I'm just paranoid :D

Comment: I'm leaning toward the latter (_i.e._ paranoid), but I suppose there's no such thing as having **too much** security. :D